# Golang smtp.NewClient took so long

Tags: go, email, ubuntu, smtp, vps

I have problem with golang function `smtp.NewClient`.

I have two server, one at GCP and one is a VPS at another local provider (Ubuntu).

I want to send an email use golang. This is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/smtp"
)

// EmailConfiguration struct.
type EmailConfiguration struct {
    From     string
    Host     string
    Port     string
    Username string
    Password string
}

func main() {

    config := EmailConfiguration{
        Host:     "some.host.tld",
        Port:     "465",
        Username: "user@some.host.tld",
        Password: "password",
        From:     "user@some.host.tld",
    }

    sendMail(config, "email@host.com", "Hi", "This is email test")
}

func sendMail(config EmailConfiguration, to, subject, message string) {

    mime := "MIME-version: 1.0;\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\";\n\n"
    subject = "Subject: " + subject + "\n"
    body := "From: " + config.From + "\n" + "To: " + to + "\n"
    body += subject + mime + "\n" + message

    servername := config.Host + ":" + config.Port

    host, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(servername)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Plain Auth...")
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", config.Username, config.Password, host)

    tlsconfig := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
        ServerName:         host,
    }

    log.Println("Dialing...")
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", servername, tlsconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Dial: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Create new client...")
    c, err := smtp.NewClient(conn, host)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Client: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Authenticate...")
    if err = c.Auth(auth); err != nil {
        log.Println("Auth: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Mail...")
    if err = c.Mail(config.From); err != nil {
        log.Println("From: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Receipt...")
    if err = c.Rcpt(to); err != nil {
        log.Println("To: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Data...")
    w, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Data: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Write body...")
    _, err = w.Write([]byte(body))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Write: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Close...")
    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Close: ", err)
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println("Quit...")
    c.Quit()
}
```

The email sent immediately in GCP. But, when I run it on the local provider server, there are some delay at the `smtp.NewClient` function.

The SMTP Server is at another local provider that use cPanel to manage.

I don't think there are blocking port, because it could send the email, but delay for about 10 seconds.

Is any solution for this problems?

Comment: The reason for such a delay is outside of the code. So  no fix in the code will help.

Comment: Hi, @SteffenUllrich yes it is. The server provider told me to do traceroute and it hop many server.